# What is the git checkout master vs git checkout origin/master

Tags: git, git-checkout

What is the difference between the following commands?

```
git checkout master vs git checkout origin/master
```

Answer (score 11):

`git checkout master` checks out a local branch. Typical.

`git checkout origin/master` looks similar and could suggest that you want to checkout a branch, but there the ref is a *remote-tracking* branch. These refs are **not** local branches, they're images of some remote's (`origin`) branches, which are only updated through `git fetch`.
Checking them out like you would for a local branch is not allowed by git architecture, so it falls down to the next best thing : checking out *the commit* this ref is currently pointing at.

The result (of checking out a commit directly rather than a branch) is what's called a `detached HEAD state`. Harmless despite its name, it just means that your `HEAD` is currently pointing at a commit directly, not a branch. Which is "solved" by checking out a branch.

Comment: Probably a daft question but what happens if you have a local branch named "origin/master"  is that even a thing?

Comment: Yes, you technically can. It's often the result of a bad `git branch` command, and is indeed confusing, but it can be done. (Don't)